# Find in mysql within 2 variable (mybe unique value ) i dont find better title

Tags: php, mysql, find

Anyone knows how can find ?
i have 3 column

1- id

2 - username

3- ip

and the sample data is :

```
+----+-----------+----------------+
| id | username  |    ip          |
+----+-----------+----------------+
|  1 | John      |  127.0.0.1     | 
|  2 | John      |  127.0.0.1     | 
|  3 | John      |  127.0.0.1     | 
|  4 | John      |  127.0.0.1     | 
|  5 | John      |  127.0.0.1     | 
|  6 | John      |  127.0.0.2     | 
|  7 | John      |  127.0.0.2     | 
|  8 | John      |  127.0.0.3     | 
|  9 | John      |  127.0.0.1     | 
| 10 | John      |  127.0.0.1     | 
| 11 | John      |  127.0.0.1     | 
| 12 | Pit       |  127.1.1.1     | 
| 13 | Pit       |  127.1.1.1     | 
| 14 | Pit       |  127.1.1.1     | 
| 15 | Pit       |  127.1.1.1     | 
| 16 | Pit       |  127.1.1.1     | 
| 17 | Pit       |  127.1.1.1     | 
+----+-----------+----------------+
```

so i want find any of value have duplicated ip
in better case i want find unique value so with this query i can find it :

```
SELECT distinct `username`, `ip` FROM `logs`
```

now the query result is

```
+----+-----------+----------------+
| id | username  |    ip          |
+----+-----------+----------------+
|  1 | John      |  127.0.0.1     | 
|  7 | John      |  127.0.0.2     | 
|  8 | John      |  127.0.0.3     | 
| 12 | Pit       |  127.1.1.1     | 
+----+-----------+----------------+
```

it's good but what i really want ?
i want find any of username have duplicate ip so the result must :

```
+----+-----------+----------------+
| id | username  |    ip          |
+----+-----------+----------------+
|  1 | John      |  127.0.0.1     | 
|  7 | John      |  127.0.0.2     | 
|  8 | John      |  127.0.0.3     | 
+----+-----------+----------------+
```

because in there pit dont have duplicate ip
how can i remove pit from the result ?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following -

```
SELECT `logs`.`username`, `logs`.`ip`
FROM (
    SELECT `username`
    FROM `logs`
    GROUP BY `username`
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `ip`) > 1
) AS `dups`
INNER JOIN `logs`
    ON `dups`.`username` = `logs`.`username`
GROUP BY `logs`.`username`, `logs`.`ip`;
```

**UPDATE** Adding an index on username and ip makes a big difference to the performance of this query as the dataset grows -

```
CREATE INDEX `IX_username_ip` ON `logs` (`username`, `ip`);
```

Comment: thank you so much it's good and work fine , but i dont know how this query work ? can you please give me a reference how you make this query?

Comment: The inner query (derived table dups) just creates a list of the usernames for which there is more than one ip. This is then joined back to the logs table to retrieve the ip addresses.

Comment: Please accept this answer if you are happy with it. Just click on the tick to the left of the answer you want to accept.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct `username`, `ip` 
FROM `logs`
WHERE `username` 
  IN (SELECT `username`
      FROM `logs`
      GROUP BY `username`
      HAVING COUNT(*) >1)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT l1.username, l1.ip FROM logs l1
INNER JOIN logs l2
    ON l2.username = l1.username
    AND l2.ip != l1.ip
GROUP BY l1.username, l1.ip
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   select distinct username,group_concat( distinct ip ) ,count(distinct ip) as cnt from table_name group by username  having cnt>1;
```

Comment: @user131;  have you downvoted this because it not helped or you have not even given it a try?

Comment: It does not produce the result he was looking for and you missed out the `GROUP BY username`

Comment: @nnichols group by username is not required here and group_concat also works without group by and is that you who downvoted my answer

Comment: I did not downvote your answer. Your query will not give the desired result without the `GROUP BY`!